# mysql finding field population of multiple columns the efficient way?

Tags: mysql

I have a large table in mysql with 150 columns (not my design)

and Im working on finding the population of each column (not empty string)

I have a table

```
email | fname | lname | ... | ... |
aaa   | bbb   | ccc   | rrr | qqq |
bbb   | eee   | ''    | ddd | bbb |
...   | ...   | ''    | ccc | eee |
```

desire result (format does not matter actually)

```
fields | # population     | % population
email  | 1501203          | 100
fname  | 1450000          | 95
lname  | ...              | ....
...
```

my code so far

```
SELECT 'email' as col1  ,COUNT(NULLIF( Email, '' )) as '#Populated'
                        , (COUNT(NULLIF( Email, '' ))  * 100/ (Select count(*) 
from mytable)) as '% pupolation'
FROM mytable
union 
SELECT 'fname'...
*repeat code above 150 times...*
```

is there a better way to do this?

i dont necessarily need to list the column names in 1 column, it just looks nicer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`(COUNT(NULLIF( Email, '' ))` --> `COUNT(Email)`

`COUNT(col)` is the same as `COUNT(*)` except for ignoring rows when `col` is `NULL`.

So..

```
SELECT
    COUNT(Email)              AS '#Email',
    COUNT(Email)*100/COUNT(*) AS '%Email',
    COUNT(fname)              AS '#fname',
    COUNT(fname)*100/COUNT(*) AS '%fname',
    ...
```

would give you 300 columns.

For 150 rows:

```
SELECT
    'Email'                   AS 'Column',
    COUNT(Email)              AS '# Populated',
    COUNT(Email)*100/COUNT(*) AS '% Populated'
    FROM tbl
UNION ALL
SELECT
    'fname',
    COUNT(fname),
    COUNT(fname)*100/COUNT(*)
    FROM tbl
UNION ALL
...
```

Notes:

- The former uses one pass over the data; the latter needs 150 passes.
- If you are using the commandline mysql, use `\G` to make the display more readable.
- `UNION` defaults to `UNION DISTINCT`, which makes an extra pass over the result to de-dup.  `UNION ALL` skips that; it is unnecessary in *your* case.
- The `AS` is needed on only the first `SELECT` of a `UNION`.  (If present on others, it is ignored.)

If you want to turn `NULL` into `0`, be more efficient by doing the test outside the count:

```
    IFNULL(COUNT(Email), 0)              AS '# Populated',
    IFNULL(COUNT(Email), 0)*100/COUNT(*) AS '% Populated'
```

Other counting techniques:

```
SUM(Email != '')        -- excludes both NULLs and empty strings
SUM(Email IS NOT NULL)  -- excludes NULLs  (Same as COUNT(Email))
SUM(Email IS NULL)      -- includes only NULLs
```

A boolean expression evaluates to 0 or 1 (or `NULL`); `SUM` then adds up the ones.

Comment: thanks a lot! your code is 100x cleaner. I was running my older code before you posted and got an error`Msg 8115, Level 16, State 2, Line 2` probably because my table has 150 million rows...other than null value, i also need to find "not empty strings" for my case. So the code you provided actually gave me 100% population for each original column (because instead of "null" we just dont have anything in empty cells at all)...is there a way to fix that?

Comment: did a quick fix and changed from COUNT() TO COUNT_BIG()...will see what happens tomorrow lol

Comment: @ChrisK - I added some more.